# Why don't I get "thread_inst_executed"

Tags: cuda, gpu, profiling, nvidia, nvprof

When I list nvprof's metrics with

```sh
nvprof --query-events
```

I see:

> thread_inst_executed:  Number of instructions executed by the active threads. For each instruction it increments by number of threads, including predicated-off threads, that execute the instruction. It does not include replays.

I would like to use this metric, so I collect metrics using:

> `nvprof --csv --metrics thread_inst_executed,inst_executed,inst_executed_global_loads,inst_executed_global_stores,inst_executed_local_loads,inst_executed_local_stores,inst_executed_shared_loads,inst_executed_shared_stores,gld_transactions,gst_transactions,local_load_transactions,local_store_transactions,shared_load_transactions,shared_store_transactions,l2_read_transactions,l2_write_transactions,dram_read_transactions,dram_write_transactions,sysmem_read_transactions,sysmem_write_transactions ./my_program my arguments`

The output has every metric I asked for... except `thread_inst_executed`. Why is it missing? How can I get it?

Comment: because events and metrics are not the same thing.  On one hand, you queried events.  On the other hand, you asked for metrics, but provided the name of an event.  If you actually want to list nvprof's metrics, you should do `--query-metrics` not `--query-events` https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#event-summary-mode

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That's working for me if you'd like to write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Richard: feel free to add your own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I list nvprof's **metrics** with

> nvprof --query-**events**

That isn't consistent usage (emphasis added).

Using `nvprof` (or `nvvp`), **events** and **metrics** are [not the same thing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#event-summary-mode).

To query events, you would use:

```
--query-events
```

To query metrics, you would use:

```
--query-metrics
```

To profile, asking for an event measurement, you would use

```
--events name_of_event,...
```

To profile, asking for a metric measurement, you would use

```
--metrics name_of_metric,...
```

If you do something like this:

```
--metrics name_of_event,...
```

or

```
--events name_of_metric,...
```

I don't know what the behavior is, but I would not expect it to work properly.

Comment: The behaviour was that the unrecognised metric was silently dropped. You can specify both metrics and events in the same call to nvprof, so that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for your help!